# Can rundeck jobs be executed sequentially?

Tags: rundeck, control-m

I am migrating a client from Control-M to a more modern solution. Client is running workloads in AWS, and has been considering using Rundeck to replace Control-M.

The control-m jobs run sequentially (one after another) only when the previous jobs terminates successfully.

A few of the jobs run in parallel (1 or more of the parallel jobs do not have dependent *"child"* jobs), but almost all run sequentially.

Does rundeck support running jobs sequentially? How can this be achieved?

Edit 1: client has over 500 jobs, with one command (shell) each. Target node is ec2 instance in same VPC with ssh public key authn configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Strategy of your Job, for that Create or Edit your job and go to Workflow tab > Strategy = Sequential, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tLbL.jpg).

You have a complete explanation of strategies [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#workflow-control-settings) and [here](https://www.rundeck.com/blog/howto-controlling-how-and-where-rundeck-jobs-execute).

EDIT 2: I leave an example focused on jobs using [Job Reference Step](https://online.rundeck.com/plugins/job-reference-step).

Job A

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>7e85b6ff-4813-4f94-85f2-2b91ff359fd4</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobA</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
          <command>
            <exec>sleep 2; echo "i am the job a"</exec>
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>7e85b6ff-4813-4f94-85f2-2b91ff359fd4</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

Job B

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>859788d6-1fef-4467-8ce9-bc34ef6735e2</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobB</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
          <command>
            <exec>sleep 2; echo "i am the job b"</exec>
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>859788d6-1fef-4467-8ce9-bc34ef6735e2</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

Job C

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>458d13d1-7436-4d7e-b7a2-382a5bea449f</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobC</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
          <command>
            <exec>sleep 2; echo "i am the job c"</exec>
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>458d13d1-7436-4d7e-b7a2-382a5bea449f</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

The parent job with Job Reference Step:

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>af4b4937-f4c2-4d73-ba8e-0ccc50bc6479</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>ParentJob</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='sequential'>
          <command>
            <jobref name='JobA' nodeStep='true'>
              <uuid>7e85b6ff-4813-4f94-85f2-2b91ff359fd4</uuid>
            </jobref>
          </command>
          <command>
            <jobref name='JobB' nodeStep='true'>
              <uuid>859788d6-1fef-4467-8ce9-bc34ef6735e2</uuid>
            </jobref>
          </command>
          <command>
            <jobref name='JobC' nodeStep='true'>
              <uuid>458d13d1-7436-4d7e-b7a2-382a5bea449f</uuid>
            </jobref>
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>af4b4937-f4c2-4d73-ba8e-0ccc50bc6479</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

For example, if any job fails, the execution stops. With Rundeck 3.2.0 Enterprise, you can use the [Job Resume](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/execution-lifecycle/job-resume.html) feature to retake the execution at the failed step (only for sequential strategy).

Comment: I only have 1 node. Will setting the Strategy = Sequential cause jobs to run only when previous jobs terminate successfully? How does one create a dependency map of the  jobs? `A-->B-->C-->N`

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer with an example and the "job resume" feature (for Rundeck 3.2 Enterprise).

Comment: Is this showing _**commands**_ being run sequentially, or _**jobs**_? I need jobs to be run sequentially. Each job has one command.

Comment: You're right! For that you can use the Job Reference Step as steps in a parent Job referencing your jobs sequentially, my example is updated.